# Elasticsearch setup:upgrade error: No handler for type [text] declared on field [search]

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2.2.4, elasticsearch

I am trying to install [`smile/elasticsuite`](https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/) using composer but I am getting a really strange error.

To install the module I used:

> composer require smile/elasticsuite:2.6.0

And got successful response:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing react/promise (v2.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (3.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/ringphp (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (v5.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing smile/elasticsuite (2.6.0): Loading from cache
Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Then run following:

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento cache:flush

Now, on the front-end, I get the following error message:

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog data: current version - none, required version - 1.5.0
Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogRule data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogOptimizer data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.0
Smile_ElasticsuiteSwatches data: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1
Smile_ElasticsuiteThesaurus data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Smile_ElasticsuiteTracker data: current version - none, required version - 1.2.0
Smile_ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory data: current version - none, required version - 1.3.0
```

Updates the Magento software doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After adding the missing configurations, I get an error on `bin/magento setup:upgrade`:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "No handler for type [text] declared on field [search]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "No handler for type [text] declared on field [search]"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Result of curl:

```
{
  "name" : "Squidboy",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "0L1pnmTiQBaWL21J5p5iPw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.5",
    "build_hash" : "c849dd13904f53e63e88efc33b2ceeda0b6a1276",
    "build_timestamp" : "2017-04-24T16:18:17Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure your ElasticServer is up and running. You can use the following CLI commands to test the availability and the outcome:

> curl localhost:9200

```
{
  "name" : "xN9wlEs",
  "cluster_name" : "clustername",
  "cluster_uuid" : "DC9ipvdISOyw0i3dqsrTzQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.4.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "595516e",
    "build_date" : "2018-08-17T23:18:47.308994Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Pleas keep in mind that the ElasticSuite ^2.6 supports ElasticSearch 6.x so use it. A lot of things got fixed enhanced on that version. Also ElasticSuite ^2.6 is not compatible with ElasticSearch 2.x.

---

**Installing ElasticSearch 6.x**

For a detailed instruction "tutorial" please refer to the official Smile_Elasticsuite documentary to get everything correct

```
https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/ServerConfig-5.x#installing-elasticsearch
```

After you installed and configured ElasticSearch and ElasticSuite do the following steps:

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> Clear magento Cache

Comment: Hi Marcel! Thanks for reaching out! I updated my answer with the result of curl. Looks a bit different from your, do you spot anything wrong in the response?

Comment: Looks like you have installed an old version of ElasticSearch, but thats not that bad - We can fix all the problems. Whats your installed version of the Smile_ElasticSuite and your Magento Version?

Comment: I use **Magento ver. 2.2.4** and installed the Smile_ElasticSuite:2.6.0

Comment: Based on your `curl` request your installed ElasticSearch version is `"number" : "2.4.5"`. In order to make it work with Magento 2.2.x and ElasticSuite 2.6.x you need to install ElasticSearch 6.x. Please make sure to install the correct version of ElasticSearch (dont get mixed up with ElasticSuite and ElasticSearch - Theese are 2 different things. Take the ElasticSuite as Gateway and ElasticSearch as the actuall Searchprovider). You can find the correct ElasticSearch version here: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

Comment: Great, I will install the Elasticsearch 6.x and see if that solved the problem! I will let you know if that solved the problem but I believe it will :)

Comment: In case of a problem feel free to comment :) Ill take a look at it as soon as possible

Comment: Upgraded and worked as expected :) Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This module need running elasticsearch and need pre-configuration. So open app/etc/env.php and added this after install index:

```
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'smile_elasticsuite_core_base_settings' => [
            'es_client' => [
                'servers' => 'localhost:9200',
                'enable_https_mode' => 0,
                'enable_http_auth' => 0,
                'http_auth_user' => '',
                'http_auth_pwd' => '',
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Now looks like

```
'install' => [
'date' => 'Sat, 02 Jun 2018 13:40:02 +0000'
],
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'smile_elasticsuite_core_base_settings' => [
            'es_client' => [
                'servers' => 'localhost:9200',
                'enable_https_mode' => 0,
                'enable_http_auth' => 0,
                'http_auth_user' => '',
                'http_auth_pwd' => '',
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Now run **setup:upgrade** command.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply. Tried this but with no success, still the same error.

Comment: Ignore above comment. You are correct, there were some configs missing. I get a different error on `setup:upgrade` now. See my updated question.

Comment: Also, congratulations on getting M2 Solution Specialist Certificate :)

Answer (score 1):

That means you didn't enable these Modules before setup upgrade.

run: **`bin/magento module:enable --all`**

after that run **bin/magento setup:upgrade**

just before your answer updated. You must install Elastic Server before config elastic to connect. 
------------ DONE Update 1:

------------ Next Update about error text

I think that you have installed the newest version of Elastic on the server. You must use Elastic 2.4.4 it as stable as newest with Magento 2

Which version should I use ?

```
Magento Version ElasticSuite Latest Version
Magento 2.0.x Opensource (CE) / Commerce (EE)   ElasticSuite 2.1.x latest release : composer require smile/elasticsuite ^2.1.0
Magento 2.1.x Opensource (CE) / Commerce (EE)   ElasticSuite 2.3.x latest release : composer require smile/elasticsuite ^2.3.0
Magento 2.2.x Opensource (CE) / Commerce (EE)   ElasticSuite 2.6.x latest release : composer require smile/elasticsuite ^2.6.0
```

Issue Link:
https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/985

Comment: The modules are enabled. Running `bin/magento module:status` gave me **List of disabled modules: None**

Comment: Have you check these modules has available in your source code?? 
**Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog**

Comment: Yeah, the code base is present in vendor.

Comment: remove the config in env.php ?? make sure didn't change anything? I mean revert you added config before asking this question.

Comment: bin/magento module:status | grep Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog ??

Comment: The output of above: Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog
Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogRule
Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogOptimizer

Comment: Updated answer.